# Initial Value Problem for an Inhomogeneous Equation

Tags: partial-differential-equations

Find the solution of this initial value problem.

$u_t = 2u_{xx} + 6u$, $0<x<\pi$, $t>0$

$u(0,t) = 0 = u(\pi,t)$, $t>0$

$u(x,0)=5\sin3x-2\sin4x+3\sin10x$.

Can someone help get me started?

Answer (score 2):

Let us use separation of variables. This means we assume that $u(x,t)$ takes the form
$$
u(x,t) = X(x)T(t)
$$
Plugging in to the original equation gives:
$$
X(x)T'(t) = 2X''(x)T(t) + 6X(x)T(t)
$$
Dividing through by $X(x)T(t)$:
$$
\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} = 2\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} + 6
$$
The left hand side is dependent only on $t$ and the right hand side is dependent only on $x$, yet they equal each other for all $(x,t)$. The only way this can be true is if each side is constant:
$$
2\frac{X''(x)}{X(x)} + 6 = -\lambda
$$
$$
\frac{T'(t)}{T(t)} = -\lambda
$$
Reordering the first equation gives
$$
X''(x) + \frac{\lambda+6}{2}X(x) = 0
$$
If we let $k^2=\frac{\lambda+6}{2}$, the general solution to this equation is
$$
X(x) = c_1\sin(kx)+c_2\cos(kx)
$$
Now because $u(0,t)=u(\pi,t)=0$, this translates to $X(0)=X(\pi)=0$. This is only possible if the $\cos$ term vanishes and $k$ takes on certain discrete values to match those boundary conditions. We get a family of solutions
$$
X_n(x) = c_n\sin(k_n x),\;\;k_n=n
$$
Now we return to the time equation, this time knowing that the values of the unknown constant are restricted to discrete values $\lambda_n=2k_n^2-6$; reordering that gives
$$
T_n'(t) + \lambda_n T_n(t) = 0
$$
With solution family
$$
T_n(t) = e^{-\lambda_n t}
$$
Now $u$ has a solution family
$$
u_n(x,t) = X_n(x)T_n(t) = c_n\sin(k_n x)e^{-\lambda_n t}
$$
That is a solution for any integer value of $n$, so the most general solution is a superposition of those solutions
$$
u(x,t) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty u_n(x,t) =
\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n\sin(k_n x)e^{-\lambda_n t}
$$
To determine the unknown $c_n$ coefficients, we have to apply the initial condition
$$
5\sin(3x)-2\sin(4x)+3\sin(10x) = u(x,0) = \sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty c_n\sin(k_n x)
$$
Recalling that $k_n=n$, it is clear that the sequence of $c_n$ values is mostly zero, except that $c_3=5,\;c_4=-2,\;c_{10}=3$. So the final solution is 
$$
u(x,t) = 5\sin(3 x)e^{-12 t}-2\sin(4 x)e^{-26 t}+3\sin(10 x)e^{-194 t}
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\+}{^{\dagger}}%
 \newcommand{\angles}[1]{\left\langle #1 \right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace #1 \right\rbrace}%
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack #1 \right\rbrack}%
 \newcommand{\ceil}[1]{\,\left\lceil #1 \right\rceil\,}%
 \newcommand{\dd}{{\rm d}}%
 \newcommand{\down}{\downarrow}%
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\equalby}[1]{{#1 \atop {= \atop \vphantom{\huge A}}}}%
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,{\rm e}^{#1}\,}%
 \newcommand{\fermi}{\,{\rm f}}%
 \newcommand{\floor}[1]{\,\left\lfloor #1 \right\rfloor\,}%
 \newcommand{\half}{{1 \over 2}}%
 \newcommand{\ic}{{\rm i}}%
 \newcommand{\iff}{\Longleftrightarrow}
 \newcommand{\imp}{\Longrightarrow}%
 \newcommand{\isdiv}{\,\left.\right\vert\,}%
 \newcommand{\ket}[1]{\left\vert #1\right\rangle}%
 \newcommand{\ol}[1]{\overline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left( #1 \right)}%
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\pp}{{\cal P}}%
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,#2\,}\,}%
 \newcommand{\sech}{\,{\rm sech}}%
 \newcommand{\sgn}{\,{\rm sgn}}%
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{{\rm d}^{#1} #2}{{\rm d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\ul}[1]{\underline{#1}}%
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\, #1 \,\right\vert}$
$$
{\rm u}\pars{x,t}=
{\rm A}_{3}\pars{t}\sin\pars{3x} - {\rm A}_{4}\pars{t}\sin\pars{4x}
+ {\rm A}_{10}\pars{t}\sin\pars{10x}
$$

> \begin{align}
> &\dot{{\rm A}}_{3}\pars{t}\sin\pars{3x} - \dot{{\rm A}}_{4}\pars{t}\sin\pars{4x}
> + \dot{{\rm A}}_{10}\pars{t}\sin\pars{10x}
> \\[3mm]&=
> \bracks{-18{\rm A}_{3}\pars{t}\sin\pars{3x} + 32{\rm A}_{4}\pars{t}\sin\pars{4x}
> -200 {\rm A}_{10}\pars{t}\sin\pars{10x}}
> \\[3mm]&\phantom{=}+
> \bracks{6{\rm A}_{3}\pars{t}\sin\pars{3x} - 6{\rm A}_{4}\pars{t}\sin\pars{4x}
> + 6{\rm A}_{10}\pars{t}\sin\pars{10x}}
> \end{align}

$$\left\lbrace%
\begin{array}{rcrclrcr}
\dot{\rm A}_{3}\pars{t} & + & 12\,{\rm A}_{3}\pars{t} & = & 0\,,\qquad
&{\rm A}_{3}\pars{0} & = & 5
\\[1mm]
\dot{\rm A}_{4}\pars{t} & + & 26\,{\rm A}_{4}\pars{t} & = & 0\,,\qquad
&{\rm A}_{4}\pars{0} & = & -2
\\[1mm]
\dot{\rm A}_{3}\pars{t} & + & 194\,{\rm A}_{3}\pars{t} & = & 0\,,\qquad
&{\rm A}_{10}\pars{0} & = & 3
\end{array}\right.
$$

> $$
> {\rm A}_{3}\pars{t} = 4\expo{-12t}\,,\qquad
> {\rm A}_{4}\pars{t} = -2\expo{-26t}\,,\qquad
> {\rm A}_{3}\pars{t} = 3\expo{-194t}
> $$

$$
\color{#00f}{\large{\rm u}\pars{x,t}=
4\sin\pars{3x}\expo{-12t} + 2\sin\pars{4x}\expo{-26t}
+ 3\sin\pars{10x}\expo{-194t}}
$$

Comment: I like this approach, very nice. There are several typos/errors, however, that cause the final answer to not solve the original equation and boundary conditions.